# How to disable automatic painting for TLabel?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, tform, tpanel, tlabel

I have a `TForm` with a `TTreeView` and a `TPanel`, where the Panel is associated with a `TLabel`.

In my `TTreeView`, there are nodes with text that is too long to be fully displayed, so a scrollbar is automatically generated. Since my `TLabel` serves as a header, I use `TextOutA` to print my label every time the position of the `TTreeView` changes.

All of this is already working; however, I now face the issue that the Label seems to be redrawn when I shift the focus from my application to my second monitor, resulting in incorrect display.

Does anyone have an idea on how to possibly solve this problem?

```cpp
void __fastcall TShortView2Form::HeadlineDrawing(void)
{
    TRect LabelRect;

    LabelRect = TitelLabel->ClientRect;
    TitelLabel->Canvas->Brush->Color = Panel1->Color;
    LabelRect.Left = DefaultLeftPosition - 20;
    TitelLabel->Canvas->FillRect(LabelRect);  // Fill the Pannel, with his Background Color, therefore                     it is blank

    LabelRect.Left = DefaultLeftPosition - 20; // -20, for the Correct Position of the Drawing
    TitelLabel->Canvas->Font->Color = clBlack;
    TitelLabel->Canvas->Font->Style += TitelLabel->Canvas->Font->Style << fsBold;
    TitelLabel->Canvas->TextOutA(LabelRect.Left, LabelRect.Top, TitelLabel->Caption);

    TitelLabel->Canvas->Font->Style -= TitelLabel->Canvas->Font->Style << fsBold;
}

void __fastcall TShortView2Form::TreeView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(TCustomTreeView *Sender,
    TTreeNode *Node, TCustomDrawState State, TCustomDrawStage Stage,
    bool &PaintImages, bool &DefaultDraw)
{
    bool bHeadlineDraw = true;
    if (Node->Level == 0)
    {
        TRect Rect;
        Rect = Node->DisplayRect(true);

        if (DefaultLeftPosition != Rect.Left)
        {
            DefaultLeftPosition = Rect.Left;

            if (Stage == cdPostPaint)
            {
                HeadlineDrawing();
                bHeadlineDraw = false;
            }
        }
    }

    Sender->Canvas->Brush->Color = clWhite;
    Sender->Canvas->Font->Color = clBlack;

    bool bIsSelected = State.Contains(cdsFocused);
    if (bIsSelected && bHeadlineDraw && Stage == cdPostPaint)
    {
        HeadlineDrawing();
        bHeadlineDraw = false;
    }
}
```

My Form normally looks like this:

[image: Form with the right look]

This is what my Form looks when I switch to my second screen:

[image: Form with false look]

I have already tried checking, if there are any changes when I invoke the `Headlinedrawing()` function in the `OnPaint` event of the `TForm`. However, this doesn't make any difference.

I have also verified that my function doesn't print the text in the wrong place for confirmation, but this is not the case, either.

Comment: How exactly is the display incorrect? Can you provide screenshots? In any case - "*Since my TLabel serves as a header, I use TextOutA to print my label every time the position of the TTreeView changes*" - that isn't the correct way to handle this. You are drawing on the Label outside of its own paint cycle. You should just set the Label's `Caption` when the TreeView changes and let the Label handle its own drawing normally. For that matter, why do you have a Label on top of the TreeView at all? You could just draw your text directly onto the TreeView's `Canvas` while the TreeView is painting.

Comment: I chose this drawing approach because my header remains constant; only what is displayed varies. I didn't want to alter the text of the panel every time I use the horizontal scrollbar of the TreeView.

Drawing it directly on the TreeView seemed incorrect, as I didn't want it to be a node of the TreeView. Unfortunately, I haven't found any other way to have a header on the TreeView.

I provided the screenshots in the Post. And thanks a lot for the respons.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you add the header text as a tree node. In any case, I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish and I still think it's the wrong approach. I would handle the header using a ScrollBox or PaintBox instead. But, what you have shown is very grid-like so I wonder why you're using a TreeView instead of a ListView. If you really want a TreeView with columns and headers, a much better approach is to use a 3rd party TreeView which has these features built in, such as VirtualTreeView.

Comment: You're right; the whole concept here is flawed. The only problem is that I've been assigned this task and now I have to somehow solve it.

The previous format of this display was a ListView. Now, however, they want to implement the functionality of a TreeView. Therefore, I haven't really found another way than reproducing the old format with a TreeView. I will look, if they allow a 3rd party TreeView, but i do not really think so.

Comment: If you have to use `TTreeView`, I would suggest putting a `TLabel` (or better a `THeaderControl`) onto a `TScrollBox`. Set its `Width` to the `TTreeView.Width`, disable its border/bevel and visible scrollbars, and set its `HorzScrollBar.Range` to the `TLabel.Width` (or `THeaderControl`). Then, hook `TTreeView.WindowProc` to handle `WM_HSCROLL` messages (or use a `TTimer`/`TActionList`/etc to call `Windows.GetScrollInfo()` periodically) to detect when the `TTreeView` scrolls and call `TScrollBox.ScrollBy()` accordingly. Took me a few minutes to work it out, it works nice, and no custom drawing.

Comment: I have tried this code on a test software, `ScrollBy()` does not work, could you show me the code for it

Comment: It does work, or I would not have suggested it. Whether it solves the multiple monitor issue, that I don't know, as I don't have a 2nd monitor to treat with. But anytime you can let the OS do its normal work is a good thing. I'll post an example later today

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that your code isn't functioning; rather, I'm experiencing difficulty programming it. It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide an example

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to it today, I'll post an example tomorrow